# Different vat rate per commerce shipping service

Tags: commerce

I have a complex shipping price grid, with :

- Different modes : tracked or not
- Different zones : France, EU, World
- Different prices per weight steps (<250g, <400g, etc.)

I started to implement that using Commerce shipping, Commerce flat rate and Commerce physical products, and a lot of rules, but now I need to apply a fixed VAT rate (20%) on shipping ONLY for tracked shipping in France.

Any idea of how I can do that? The VAT rate rule calculation seems to apply everytime, I don't know how to say "only for tracked shipping service".

Maybe it's time to make my own shipping module?

Comment: Ok, it seems it can be done with a condition on the VAT rate rule, if I use a PHP code condition, I can test the shipping line item.

Answer (score 0):

As the author answered in a comment, this can be achieved by adding a rule condition to the rule that applies the VAT rate. Often pricing tables requires custom PHP code. Though, it's better to create a custom module and define your own rule condition in code.

You just have to implement one of the following hooks:

**Custom Rules Action** (not what you need, but good to know)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info()
 */
function MODULE_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'machine_name' => array(
      'label' => 'Custom Action',
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * machine_name custom action
 */
function machine_name() {
  // do action
}
```

**Custom Rules Condition** (definitely what you need)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_condition_info()
 */
function MODULE_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'machine_name_condition' => array(
      'label' => 'Custom Condition',
      'arguments' => array(
        'type' => 'user', // there are lots of types
        'label' => 'Fancy user',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * machine_name_condition custom rules condition
 */
function machine_name_condition($user) {
  if ($user->uid == 1) return true;
  return false;
}
```